# Amazon Product Advertising API final price

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I get the final price?

```
ItemLookupRequest: 
{ Condition: 'New',
IdType: 'ISBN',
ItemId: '0439708184',
ResponseGroup: [ 'Small', 'Offers' ],
SearchIndex: 'All',
VariationPage: 'All' } }
```

[This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059035342X) has list price of $10.99 but the real final price listed is $7.48, it's promoted, however, the above API call gets me $5.34 in the `LowestNewPrice` response field, as mentioned under "Paperback": "181 New from $5.34"!

Again, to make it clear:
Listed price: **$10.99**
Displayed price: **$7.48**
Lowest reported price: **$5.34**

**So, if the lowest price is $5.34 why is it listed as $7.48??**

The parameters of the request above specify $5.34 but a user will be disappointed to see a price of $7.48!

So, what am I missing?

[image]